# Extra argument 'data' in call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an extra argument 'data' in call at the "addDocument(data: [".It was working fine all along,it was fine yesterday.I woke up today and run it and get this error.I am totally confused.

```
var db = Firestore.firestore()
func sendDataToDatabase(message: String){
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let timeStampString = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
      db.collection("chats").addDocument(data: [
        "message" : messageText.text!, "senderID" : senderIDNumber!, "receiverID" : receiverIDNumber!, "timestamp" : timeStampString!, "conversationsCounter" : conversationsCounterInt!
   ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `db`..?

Comment: Comment out the entire method, retype the first characters and use code completion. By the way the bold tag doesn't work in a code section.

Comment: @idmean I have edited,thks a lot.

Comment: What is does *extra argument* mean? Can you update and clarify the question indicating what line of code the error is on and what the actual error is? *db.collection("chats").addDocument(data: [* is valid and *data* is part of the function call so the question isn't making a lot of sense as is. Are you saying that your existing chats collection doesn't have (for example) a *timestamp* child so it's throwing an error?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is there is no problem with my code! It's firebase/firestore that is causing the problem.
I have been talking ,waiting for them to clean up the database for days but no one is solving the problem.

A simple debugging found that there the old data that has been deleted still remains in the firebase system.I emailed them but no one is solving my problem.

Comment: *"It's firebase/firestore that is causing the problem"* – I wonder how that would cause a “extra argument 'data' in call" compiler error.

Comment: Because firestore stores old document which has different arguments.Even though i deleted the old documents(Deleted through their console), it persists in the server.I am now trying to using command line tool to delete the document but was unable to do so.

Comment: *firebaser here* It seems unlikely that someone on the Firebase team will delete data from your database for you. What makes it that causes the "old data" to throw an error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In my old documents, i did not store the receiver profile picture url.However,in the new documents,i added in the receiver profile picture url.As my code run,it will return nil for my old documents. I have deleted the old documents from firestore console, but it still stays in the sever.I also tried using cli,i deleted the entire collections, but then the old documents still stay in the server.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried using guard but it still not functioning well.But i think thats probably the only way, have to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: If the console doesn't show data, the data is not in the server-side database anymore. However, the data may still be in the local ache on your device. If you're having a hard time making your code resilient in dealing with the double document structures, the easiest way is to wipe the cache by uninstalling/reinstalling the app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Great advice, it seems to be working for now.Will try it again after the Germany soccer match.Thks